# AngularJS $state.go not working if user not logged in

Tags: angularjs

Below i have a state in my routes.js in my angular routes controller. I want it to check if the user is an admin, and only if it is an admin it goes to admin, otherwise it is redirected to home page.

There are no errors on the console if the user is logged in and is an admin, also it redirects if the user is not an admin and logged in, but if a user is *not logged in and not an admin* i can still see the template of that page and it says `POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json 401 (Unauthorized)`

```
.state('adminpage', {
    url: '/adminpage',
    templateUrl: 'views/adminpage.html',
    controller: 'AdminPageCtrl',
    onEnter: function(Auth, $state){
      Auth.currentUser().then(function( user){
        if (user.isadmin) {
          $state.go('adminpage');
        }
        else {
          $state.go('home');
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume `Auth.currentUser()` rejects the promise if user is not logged in. So, you need to define what should be done on promise rejection, i.e. if user is not logged in.

```
onEnter: function(Auth, $state){
  Auth.currentUser().then(function( user){
    if (user.isadmin) {
      $state.go('adminpage');
    }
    else {
      $state.go('home');
    }
  })
  .catch(function() {
    // Redirect the user somewhere else, or show an error here.
  });
}
```

The `.catch()` method actually handles the rejection of the promise, and you can try to redirect the user somewhere else in this block. In this way, the restricted page won't be shown to the user.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I guess even adding error function in promise would do the redirection part.

Comment: @PankajParkar -- It works both ways. Using `catch` results in better readability, and is recommended over two callbacks in `.then()`. But yes, its a matter of personal choice.

Comment: I agree, but I like error callback, because they have ability to proceed by resolving promise.

Comment: @PankajParkar -- It totally depends on the usecase. That's why there are two methods of doing the same thing. `catch` is very useful when you're chaining promises and want to handle rejection regardless of a specific promise, which otherwise will require adding callback to each promise.